# Safari 5.1.7 download csv file with unknown as file name

Tags: javascript, csv, safari, filenames, export-to-csv

I have tried to search but didn't get any solution to my problem; here I am using the following lines of code to export data into a csv file on a mac client:

```
        var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(fileData);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = uri;
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = filename + ".csv";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
```

I figure the download attribute is not supported by Safari.

```
        "link.download!==undefined"
```

But I am not able to figure out what I should do to give a proper name to the downloaded file in Safari (version 5.1.7).

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 download attribute would have been the way to go, but that is not supported in Safari (yet).

[A post in Apple's support communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2749686?searchText=unknown%20file%20download) indicates that the "Unknown" file name with no extension is a possible Safari bug.

[This page](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/07/download-json-data-in-csv-format-cross-browser-support/) has an active following and the poster mentions he is actively searching for a solution to the Safari "Unknown" file problem, specifically as it relates to saving CSVs from a webpage.

Comment: http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/07/download-json-data-in-csv-format-cross-browser-support/
Doesn't work with safari < 6.0